# Rotation of a rod due to a normal force

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

Suppose there's a rod suspended in space free from the effect of any force. Let a force F act at a distance x from one end. How can i prove that rotation will take place about an axis passing through the centre of mass and not any other axis?

Comment: Does the force act continuously, or it is only an impulse?  What direction does it act in?  Is it constant in magnitude and/or direction?

Comment: it's an impulse... and I've already said that it's a normal force and acts normal to the rod and it's constant in magnitude and direction. it's just an initial push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rod were rotating around a point  other than the center of mass, then the center of mass would be rotating around this point. That is, the center of mass will be accelerated to perform circular motion, but we are assuming here  that there are no external forces acting on the system (other than the initial push), so the center of mass cannot accelerate. The only possibility left for an isolated system is then to rotate around an axis that pass through its center of mass.